# onChange Javascript to round this.value

Tags: onchange, innerhtml, getelementbyid, rounding

I've got the following onChange code. It updates my div1 with the value. The value is a numeric value and I would like to round it so that there is no decimal point. Can anyone tell me how this can be done?

So for example value 12.987654321 will be 13

```
onChange="document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML=this.value"
```

Comment: Can you post an example of your source on a jsfiddle please ? the context seems a little bit dark to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `Math.round` function you could use like this (otherwise your code looks fine to me):

```
onChange="document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML=Math.round(+this.value)"
```